# Successfully compile a sub-project (admin area) in Play (framework)

Tags: playframework, routes, sbt, subproject

I want to set-up an admin area as a sub-project in the ***Play Framework*** (2.6) so have been using [this documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SBTSubProjects) but am coming up with a compilation error that I just can't fix:

> [error] ...conf\routes:15: not found: value admin
>
> [error] ->  /admin admin.Routes

This is my **project structure**:

```
   main-project
   _build.sbt
   _app
     _controllers
     _models
     _views
   _conf
     _application.conf
     _routes
   _modules
     _admin
       _build.sbt
       _app
         _controllers
         _models
         _views
       _conf
         _admin.routes
   _project
     _build.properties
     _plugins.sbt
```

**main-project/build.sbt**

```
   import play.sbt.routes.RoutesKeys

   name := "main-project"

   val defaultResolvers = Seq(
     Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
   )

   lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
     organization := "com.boardrs",
     version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
     scalaVersion := "2.12.2",
     scalacOptions ++= Seq("-feature", "-language:postfixOps"),
     resolvers ++= defaultResolvers
   )


   lazy val admin = (project in file("modules/admin"))
     .settings(
       commonSettings
     ).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

   lazy val root = (project in file("."))
     .settings(
       commonSettings
     )
     .enablePlugins(PlayScala)


   routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
   RoutesKeys.routesImport += "play.modules.reactivemongo.PathBindables._"

   libraryDependencies += guice
   libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.0.0" % Test
   libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.194"
   libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.0"
   libraryDependencies += ws

   // Play 2.6.x
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
     "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.12.5-play26"
   )


   libraryDependencies += "org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "3.1.1-2"
```

**main-project/modules/admin/build.sbt**

```
name := "admin"

PlayKeys.devSettings += "play.http.router" -> "admin.Routes"
```

**main-project/conf/routes** (the file that contains the line referenced in the error)

```
       # home page
       GET     /                   controllers.HomeController.index

       ->  /admin admin.Routes

       GET     /assets/*file       controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

**main-project/modules/admin/conf/admin.routes**

```
   GET /index                  controllers.admin.HomeController.index()

   GET /assets/*file           controllers.admin.Assets.versioned(path="/public/lib/admin", file)
```

I have carefully looked here (on Stack Overflow) and elsewhere for a solution, e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315461/play-sub-projects-do-not-compile) is very similar but the answer incorporates techniques that have since been deprecated. I have tried multiple combinations but the Play Framework is a delicate beast; susceptible to a multitude of configuration and compatibility issues - so I don't feel as if I am honing in on the answer on my own. Can anyone see what I can't? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your main-project/build.sbt:

Try changing:

```
lazy val admin = (project in file("admin"))
```

to

```
lazy val admin = (project in file("modules/admin"))
```

---

I think you're missing the dependsOn and aggregateOn for the root project in your main sbt.

Try changing:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
 .settings(
   commonSettings
 )
 .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
```

to

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
 .settings(
   commonSettings
 )
 .enablePlugins(PlayScala).dependsOn(admin).aggregate(admin)
```

Comment: That's a good spot but it hasn't cleared the error. Anything else look out of place with fresh eyes?

Comment: I think you're missing the dependsOn and aggregateOn for the root project in your main sbt.